# Formatting zod schema validation errors

Tags: javascript, zod

I want to know if there is a way to reformat the schema validation errors object returned by Zod such that the error strings can include the invalid input value provided.
For example, instead of just having the error message "Number must be greater than 0.", the following error can be returned with actual value of the number: "Number must be greater than 0, but received: -3".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can pass a custom [ZodErrorMap](https://zod.dev/ERROR_HANDLING?id=customizing-errors-with-zoderrormap) to your `parse()` call which gives you access both the `issue` and a `ctx` object containing the data passed to `parse()` as well as a default message. You can then specify specific messages for each `issue.code`.

[sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/p/sandbox/nifty-architecture-r454wd?welcome=true)

```
import { z } from "zod";

const customErrorMap: z.ZodErrorMap = (error, ctx) => {
  console.log(ctx);
  /*
  This is where you override the various error codes
  */
  switch (error.code) {
    case z.ZodIssueCode.too_small:
      return {
        message: `Expected a number >= ${error.minimum} but got ${ctx.data}`,
      };
    default:
      // fall back to default message!
      return { message: ctx.defaultError };
  }
};

z.number().min(0).parse(-3, { errorMap: customErrorMap });

/*
ZodError: [
  {
    "code": "too_small",
    "minimum": 0,
    "type": "number",
    "inclusive": true,
    "exact": false,
    "message": "Expected a number >= 0 but got -3",
    "path": []
  }
]
*/
```

Error maps can be assigned at various scopes with more specific scopes taking priority over higher level maps. see [Error map priority](https://zod.dev/ERROR_HANDLING?id=error-map-priority).